# Type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to use the strongly typed view with extensions methods as

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MyUsageViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.test) %>
        </div>   
                              <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
<% } %>
    <div>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
</div>
```

I am getting the following error :

> The type arguments for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.LabelExtensions.LabelFor(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Is your model `dynamic`?

Comment: could you share your model code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your model doesn't have 'test' property which you are trying to use in Html.LabelFor helper method.

Comment: I have created the model with test property in it. The designer doesn't like anything I add to model. But if I do Model.test it is fine. It is all the extnsions method which are creating problems

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model properties are public:

```
public class LocationModel
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code does not show a definition for the type which could be the issue.  Make sure it's at the top of the page.  I'm on my tablet right now and don't have a sample to copy/paste but the syntax should be `@model modelType`

If that's not the issue, can you add the model definition and full contents of the view?

Answer (score 0):

After moving some code around to different namespaces I was seeing this same issue even though I had updated model references etc correctly. The solution was to go to build and perform a '**Clean Solution**' followed by a '**Rebuild Solution**'